# Oracle delete statement is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, oracle, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row from a table in an Oracle database using this JS function:

```
deleteDirection(directionId, callback) {
if (!this.connected) {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).asCallback(callback)
}
const connection = this.connection

const task = Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  const conn = yield connection
  const query = 'DELETE FROM directions WHERE direction_id = :directionId'
  const result = yield conn.execute(query, { directionId }, {
    outFormat: oracle.OBJECT,
  })
  .then(directionDeleted => {
    if (directionDeleted.rowsAffected === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('invalid number'))
    }
    return Promise.resolve(directionDeleted)
  })
  .catch(err => Promise.reject(new Error(err)));

  return Promise.resolve(result)
})
return Promise.resolve(task()).asCallback(callback)
}
```

The function finish without any problems but the row is not deleted, if I try the same statement on Oracle SQL Developer it works pecfectly, What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
deleteDirection(directionId, callback) {
if (!this.connected) {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).asCallback(callback)
}
const connection = this.connection

const task = Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  const conn = yield connection
  const query = 'DELETE FROM directions WHERE direction_id = :directionId'
  const result = yield conn.execute(query, { directionId:  directionId}, {
    outFormat: oracle.OBJECT,
    autoCommit: true
  })
  .then(directionDeleted => {
    if (directionDeleted.rowsAffected === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('invalid number'))
    }
    return Promise.resolve(directionDeleted)
  })
  .catch(err => Promise.reject(new Error(err)));

  return Promise.resolve(result)
})
return Promise.resolve(task()).asCallback(callback)
}
```

Notice the change to the bind variable and the use of autoCommit.

Are you using a transpiler?

Comment: you were right, the autoCommit was the solution but there's no need to change the bind variable, with { directionId } its fine, thanks for your help and yes the project has a transpiler

Answer (score 0):

Follow NodeOracle examples and pass parameters as an array:

```
const result = yield conn.execute(query, [ directionId ], {
    outFormat: oracle.OBJECT,
  })
```

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/select1.js

Comment: thanks but still without deleting, I even tried this:

const query = 'DELETE FROM directions WHERE direction_id = 630'
      const result = yield conn.execute(query, { }, {
        outFormat: oracle.OBJECT,
      })

just for test, but its not deleting

Comment: Interesting. For the sake of the test, could you do it without a generator function at all and share the results?

Comment: Hi, I already solve it, the problem was the missing of this line 'autoCommit: true' after 'outFormat: oracle.OBJECT,'